# How to select the particular value in the data table

Tags: r, shiny, datatable

1.In my app i just want to show the data of the each row separately for Ex if i click any value in the first column the data should show the whole row
like if i click on Mazda RX4 it should show the whole row of the data

2.with the help of extensions = 'ColReorder' i can drag the column inside the table if i drag the first column to others position that clickable should work

for eg if i move the 1st(new_name) column into 4th that clickeable is not working

Any answers would be appreciated

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
data("mtcars")

ui <- shinyUI(fluidRow(
  DT::dataTableOutput("myDatatable"),
  verbatimTextOutput("selectedCells")
))
df <- cbind(new_name =rownames(mtcars), data.frame(mtcars, row.names= NULL))
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$myDatatable <- DT::renderDataTable(
    df, extensions = 'ColReorder', options = list(colReorder = TRUE),selection = list(mode = "single", target ="cell"),
              server = FALSE,
              rownames = T
  )
  
  output$selectedCells <- renderPrint({
    s = input$myDatatable_cells_selected
    if (!is.null(s) && ncol(s) != 0) {
      mtcars[,1]
    } else {
      NULL
    }
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
data("mtcars")

ui <- shinyUI(fluidRow(
    DT::dataTableOutput("myDatatable"),
    verbatimTextOutput("selectedCells")
))
df <- cbind(new_name =rownames(mtcars), data.frame(mtcars, row.names= NULL))
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
    output$myDatatable <- DT::renderDataTable(
        df, extensions = 'ColReorder', options = list(colReorder = TRUE),selection = list(mode = "single", target ="cell"),
        server = FALSE,
        rownames = T
    )
    
    output$selectedCells <- renderPrint({
        
        s_val = input$myDatatable_cell_clicked$value
        s = input$myDatatable_cells_selected
        if (!is.null(s) && ncol(s) != 0) {
            df[df$new_name==s_val,]
            
        } else {
            NULL
        }
    })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have the value of selected cell with:

```
s_val = input$myDatatable_cell_clicked$value
```

After that, you can search this value in your data and print the entire row:

```
df[df$new_name==s_val,]
```

Comment: i am getting an  Warning: Error in if: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
  [No stack trace available] @jamBelg

Comment: you have to change s to s_val:    if (!is.null(s_val))